# Flex project migration to 3.4 SDK

Tags: apache-flex

I migrate from 3.0 to 3.4 SDK and see the following bug in my flex project

```
VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of FlexModuleFactory in mx.core.FlexModuleFactory.
```

How can I fix it

best
Vladimir

Comment: can you give more information on the problem? Are you using swc files? can you show us the line of code that is throwing the error?

Comment: The error thowing not at the code. The full error looks like:

accessor not implemented mx.core:IFlexModuleFactory::preloadedRSLs
   over-binding 0 in mx.core::FlexModuleFactory

method not implemented mx.core::IFlexModuleFactory/mx.core:IFlexModuleFactory::allowDomain()
   over-binding 0 in mx.core::FlexModuleFactory
VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of FlexModuleFactory in mx.core.FlexModuleFactory.

 at global$init()

method not implemented mx.core::IFlexModuleFactory/mx.core:IFlexModuleFactory::allowInsecureDomain()
   over-binding 0 in mx.core::FlexModuleFactory

Answer (score 4):

One of two things you are either trying to load a SWF that isn't a module as a module or you are loading a Module compiled with a different version of the SDK from the SWF doing the loading.

Make sure that the Module you are loading is also compiled with Flex 3.4.  Cross SDK version support is not available in Module loading.  If you need that functionality get all the loaded SWFs ( sub-applications ) up to Flex 3.3, then you can change the SDK version of the loading application ( parent application ) to whatever flex version you want.  Read up on the [Marhshall Plan](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Marshall+Plan) for more information about sub-application loading.

-d

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error on a project.  I suspect is has to do with a swc being compiled with an older version of Flex (say 3.2).  I've seen similar issues discussed online with PaperVision.  Unfortunately our project hasn't moved to 3.4 completely yet so I've not had time to recompile our various swc's to see if that fixes the the issue.